# SQL return only specific rows with specific status

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, group-by, having-clause

I have this table below with two columns

```
Order_No     Order_Status
A            Receiving
A            Active
A            Retired
A            Ordering
B            Receiving
B            Ordering 
C            Active
C            Retired
D            Receiving
E            Ordering
```

I would like to get Order_no B, D and E records because it's order status is ( Receiving/Ordering ). It should filter out A and C because both have Active and Retired status.

I tried the below query but it's not showing up the results.

```
select ORDER_NUMBER
from table ror
where ror.use_Status 
Order_Status not in ('Active', 'Retired')
and Order_Status in ('Receiving', 'Ordering').
```

Could anyone please tell me what wrong I am doing or I'm missing any joins?

Comment: Do you mean that only want to select the records from your table where order_no = B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select order_no
from mytable
group by order_no
having max(case when status = 'Receiving'            then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   and max(case when status = 'Ordering'             then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   and max(case when status not in ('Receiving', 'Ordering') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This phrases as: get all orders that have both "Receiving" and "Ordering" statuses, and no other status.

If a given order cannot have the same status twice, then the `having` can be simplified a little:

```sql
having sum(case when status     in ('Receiving', 'Ordering') then 1 else 0 end) = 2
   and sum(case when status not in ('Receiving', 'Ordering') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

---

**Edit** - if you want order that have *either* "Receiving" and "Ordering" statuses (not necessarily *both*), then a single condition is sufficient:

```sql
having max(case when status not in ('Receiving', 'Ordering') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: it breaks when there's only one record. For e.g Order_No     Order_Status
D            Receiving ....It doesnt show D record. I have updated the question again.

Comment: @shanky: it works as intended, that is *get all orders that have both "Receiving" and "Ordering" statuses*. This order does not have both statuses, so it is filtered out.

Comment: no it doesnt show D and E. I think its because of and condition.

Comment: @shanky: you don't get my point. The query I provided searches for order that have *both* statuses. `D` and `E` don't have both, they only have one of the two statuses. I edited my answer with a solution for what you ask for.